# Issues while printing json array in object on tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, alamofire

I am calling and api and i get resposne properly but i don't understand how to print an array of object like here is my response

**Response**

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 3
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        },
        {
            "month": 0
        }
    ],
    "like_data": [
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 6
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        },
        {
            "like": 0
        }
    ],
    "cmnt_data": [
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 1
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        },
        {
            "cmnt": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

so i want to print like_data and cmnt_data i have tried let me show you my code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! InstaAnalyticsTableViewCell
       let month = searchlist[indexPath.row]["month"]! as? Int
        print(month!)
        let optionalvalue = month
        if let noLongerOptional = optionalvalue {
            print("\(noLongerOptional) no its not! ahah")
            cell.lblMonthCount.text = "\(noLongerOptional)" as? String
        }

         let instaResponse = searchlist[indexPath.row]["like_data"] as! [String:Any]
         let likes = instaResponse["like"] as! Int
         cell.lblLikeCount.text = "\(likes)"
        //cell.lblMonthCount.text = "\(month)"
        return cell
    }
```

i am trying as above but i am not getting where i done wrong pelase help me to solve this and also need one help i want to display this all data as bar chart or line char so please any one help me

See here i am calling api like this way so which response i have to write

```
Alamofire.request(instaPostAnalytics, method: .post, parameters: userprofile).responseJSON
                {
                    response in

                    print(response)
                    let result = response.result
                    print(result)
                    let monthArray = yourResponse["data"] as? [[String:Int]] ?? []
                    let likeArray = yourResponse["like_data"] as? [[String:Int]] ?? []
                    let cmntArray = yourResponse["cmnt_data"] as? [[String:Int]] ?? []
                    //As of all have equal object loop like this
                    for i in 0..<min(monthArray.count, likeArray.count, cmntArray.count) {
                        let month = monthArray[i]["month"] ?? 0
                        let like = likeArray[i]["like"] ?? 0
                        let cmnt = cmntArray[i]["cmnt"] ?? 0
                        datas.append(Data(month: month, like: like, cmnt: cmnt))
                    }
                    //Now reload the tableView
                    self.yourTableView.reloadData()
//                    if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
//                        if let categorylist = dict["data"]{
//                            self.searchlist = categorylist as! [AnyObject]
//                            self.tblInstalytics.reloadData()
//                    }
//                }
            }
```

as i told yesterday i am not able to show data on chart here is my code for that

**Code**

```
        let data = response.result
        if let dict = data.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
            if let categorylist = dict["data"]{
                self.searchlist = categorylist as! [AnyObject]

                for item in self.searchlist{
                    let value = item["month"]
                    guard let value_chart = value else {
                        continue
                    }
                    let optionalvalue = value_chart
                    if let noLongerOptional = optionalvalue {
                        print("\(noLongerOptional)")
                        let chartConfig = BarsChartConfig(valsAxisConfig: ChartAxisConfig(from: 0, to: 800, by: 100))
                        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 232 )
                        let chart = BarsChart(frame: frame,
                                              chartConfig: chartConfig,
                                              xTitle: "Months",
                                              yTitle: "Count",
                                              bars: [
                                                ("Jan", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Feb", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Mar", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Apr", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("May", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Jun", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("July",noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Aug", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Sep", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Oct", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Nov", noLongerOptional as! Double),
                                                ("Dec", noLongerOptional as! Double)
                            ],
                                              color: UIColor.red,
                                              barWidth: 15
                        )
                        self.view.addSubview(chart.view)
                        self.chartView = chart
                    }
                }
            }
```

but i am not able to show and also not able to understand how show likeData and cmnt data in chart

please help me to solve this

Comment: please explain me more i am not able to understand please

Comment: Are you responsible for that awful JSON structure? If no, blame the owner of the service. An array of dictionaries containing only one key respectively is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having 3 different array in your `JSON` you should have single array which have all the value within single object of it.

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": [ {
        "month": 0,
        "like": 0,
        "cmnt": 1
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

As of for now with your current `JSON` response what you can do is make one array of `struct` or `class` and use that as datasource of tableView.

```
struct Post {
    var month: Int
    var like: Int
    var cmnt: Int
}
```

Now in your controller declare on array of `Post` and use that with your tableView methods.

```
var datas = [Post]()

//Initialize datas array like this when you get `JSON`
let result = response.result.value as? [String : Any] ?? [:]
let monthArray = result["data"] as? [[String:Int]] ?? []
let likeArray = result["like_data"] as? [[String:Int]] ?? []
let cmntArray = result["cmnt_data"] as? [[String:Int]] ?? []
//As of all have equal object loop like this
for i in 0..<min(monthArray.count, likeArray.count, cmntArray.count) {
    let month = monthArray[i]["month"] ?? 0
    let like = likeArray[i]["like"] ?? 0
    let cmnt = cmntArray[i]["cmnt"] ?? 0
    datas.append(Post(month: month, like: like, cmnt: cmnt))
}
//Now reload the tableView
self.yourTableView.reloadData()
```

Now simply change you `UITableViewDataSource` methods like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return datas.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! InstaAnalyticsTableViewCell
    let data = datas[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblMonthCount.text = String(data.month)
    cell.lblLikeCount.text = String(data.like)
    cell.lblCmntCount.text = String(data.cmnt)
    return cell        
}
```

Comment: @Nirav please check my new question

Answer (score 0):

```
//first take 3 dataArray for taking values from the response 

var likeArr = fullresponce["like_data"] as [[String:Anyobject]]
var commentArr = fullresponce["cmnt_data"] as [[String:Anyobject]]

var like = (likeArr[indexPath.row] as Dictionary)["like"]! as? Int

var cmnt = (commentArr[indexPath.row] as Dictionary)["cmnt"]! as? Int
```

Comment: here i take fullresponse as searchlist is it ok ?                                                            
var likeArr = fullresponce["like_data"] as [[String:Anyobject]]

Comment: let instaResponse = searchlist[indexPath.row]["like_data"] as! [String:Any]
         let likes = instaResponse["like"] as! string
         cell.lblLikeCount.text = "\(likes)"